# Is Manu Smriti just about Bramhin Previlage?

Tags: manu-smriti

An Anti Hindu from this website [1](https://qr.ae/pN6V1B) lists problems with Manu Smriti

- Brahmins teach that God created them from his mouth to glorify them
  and created some other castes from his feet to let them serve the
  Brahmins  Laws of Manu Chapter 1
- Brahmins urge simple people to donate and offer generous gifts to the
  Brahmins claiming that people will get hundred-thousand-fold rewards
  – Laws of Manu Chapter 7
- An offering to Brahmins saves from misfortune and from great guilt. –
  Laws of Manu Chapter 3
- Brahmin sanctifies any company (which he may enter), seven ancestors
  and seven descendants, and he alone deserves (to possess) this whole
  earth – Laws of Manu Chapter 1
- Chapter 7 teaches that Kings should honor Brahmins, should be lenient
  towards Brahmins, and should consult them in important decisions and
  should always obey them
- Hindu priests teach that money given to Brahmins is declared to be an
  imperishable treasure for kings
- Chapter 8 teaches that Brahmins are the masters of everything and
  authorizes Brahmins to decide in justice and law matters
- Chapter 9 provides exceptional inheritance rights to Brahmins
- Chapter 11 entitles Brahmins to take the law into their own hands and
  settle the disputes without referring to law and justice system of
  other castes
- Brahmin is the image of God and is the master of all castes – Laws of
  Manu Chapter 2 and 10
  Is all this true ? Are there any valid refutations to his points??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Manusmriti written to favor a particular class of the society?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32483/is-the-manusmriti-written-to-favor-a-particular-class-of-the-society)

Comment: @Ikshvaku Sir I read your answer and upvoted it. I am looking to refute his claims. Please do look at my answer.

Comment: I saw your answer and retracted the close vote. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. My aim is to defend Hinduism. Please never mistake me. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Thank you, good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to write a refutation of this article point by point in best way I can

> Brahmins teach that God created them from his mouth to glorify them
> and created some other castes from his feet to let them serve the
> Brahmins Laws of Manu Chapter 1

Reply : Purusha Sukta is Symbolic and taking literal meaning will be foolish. It can be read here [1](http://agniveer.com/vedas-caste-discrimination/)

> Brahmins urge simple people to donate and offer generous gifts to the
> Brahmins

Gifts are given to a Bramhana surely but he had also to donate them and lead an occupation earning minimum wealth.

1. Except during a time of adversity, a Brahmhana ought to sustain
   himself by following a livelihood that causes little or no harm to
   creatures. **He should gather wealth just sufficient for his
   subsistence** through irreproachable activities that are specific to
   him, without fatiguing his body. (Manu 4.2–4.3)
2. He must **never follow a worldly occupation for the sake of
   livelihood**, but subsist by means of a pure, upright and honest
   livelihood proper to a Brahmin. **One who seeks happiness should
   become supremely content and self controlled**, for happiness is
   rooted in contentment and its opposite is the root of unhappiness.
   (Manu 4.11–4.12)
3. If the twice-born person,who is without austerities and **does not
   study the Veda, seeks for gifts, he sinks along with him into water;
   just like one who sinks along with the stone-raft**(Manu 4.190)

> An offering to Brahmins saves from misfortune and from great guilt. –
> Laws of Manu Chapter 3

Hardly- Only Dharma saves one ultimately in life.

- Morality (Justice) is the only friend who follows one even after
  death; everything else perishes along with the body (Manu 8.17)

> Brahmin sanctifies any company (which he may enter), seven ancestors
> and seven descendants, and he alone deserves (to possess) this whole
> earth – Laws of Manu Chapter 1

Bramhin means one who knows Brahman. Obviously its symbolic when it says he deserves whole Earth.

> Chapter 7 teaches that Kings should honor Brahmins, should be lenient
> towards Brahmins, and should consult them in important decisions and
> should always obey them

Yes Indeed because they know Dharma very well.

> Hindu priests teach that money given to Brahmins is declared to be an
> imperishable treasure for kings

Earning money from Priest profession is condemned by Shastras : The following **five types of Brahmanas are considered to be outcastes** : Those who call out the names of accuser, defendant and witnesses in court, w**ho worship gods in temple by taking salary, who make a living by using astrology, who do the functions of a priest of villages** and who travel over ‘seas’(MB Shanti 76,Shl 1–6)

> Chapter 9 provides exceptional inheritance rights to Brahmins

It even lays most strict rules for them which can be read here : [2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18kXnWr96tCsW3xG1ehoVySg3oQKWETL9/view)