# Good and professional rebuttals to BR Ambedkars criticism and in certain cases blatant insults of the Vaidika Dharma?

Tags: untouchability, ambedkar, debate, refutation

Are there any good and academic rebuttals of BR Ambedkar's "Analysis" of our faith? This can be through putting things in a new perspective or refutations. I would like it to focus primarily on Ithihasas.

Comment: I will only say why IPC allows :adultery, smoking, alcohol, homosexuality and if ambedkar was such a genius why did he stole Constitution from many nations. Now, if they say ambedkar faced discrimination, so burnt manusmriti. My answer:If Indian judiciary doesn't give me justice, am I allowed to burn indian flag, IPC, Constitution or not. For religious question about neo buddhism and blasphemous athiesm, read satyarth prakash ch 12 http://satyarthprakash.in/english/chapter-twelve/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Manusmriti written to favor a particular Varṇa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32483/is-the-manusmriti-written-to-favor-a-particular-var%e1%b9%87a)

Comment: @ekAntika I mean a more indepth anaylsis on all his points.